# Is it possible to find zone and region of the node my container is running on

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to find the region and node of my node, I need this to log monitoring data.
kubernetes spec and metadata doesn't provide this information. I checked out
https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go which looks promising but I can't find
the info I am looking for.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

- Enabled [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

```
gcloud container clusters update <CLUSTER_NAME> \
  --workload-pool=<PROJECT_ID>.svc.id.goog
```

- Updated Node pool to use workload identity

```
gcloud container node-pools update <NODEPOOL_NAME> \
  --cluster=<CLUSTER_NAME> \
  --workload-metadata=<GKE_METADATA>
```

- Created a service account for my app
- bind my KSA to GSA

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:<PROJECT_ID>.svc.id.goog[<K8S_NAMESPACE>/<KSA_NAME]" \
  <GSA_NAME>@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

- Annotated service account using the email address of the GSA

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: <GSA_NAME>@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: KSA_NAME
  namespace: <K8S_NAMESPACE>
```

This authenticated by container with GSA and I was able to get the metadata info using https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GKE then node zone and region should be in node's labels:

```
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
topology.kubernetes.io/region
topology.kubernetes.io/zone
```

You can see node labels using `kubectl get nodes --show-labels`

Comment: These are not available from inside the container, downward API doesn't expose these either, so I can't set env var or mount info to file. (Downward API does expose labels set in the YAML file, not the ones populated dynamically)

Comment: You can also query Google Cloud Node Metadata service for node name and AZ information. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

Comment: This is not exposed to container unless you enable workload identity

Answer (score 0):

Not in any direct way. You could use the downward API to expose the node name to the pod, and then fetch the annotations/labels for that node. But that would require fairly broad read permissions (all nodes) so might be a security risk.

Comment: Yeah thats one option, as you said I am hesitant for the security risk. I wish Download API can expose these